# Having loaded profile, selenium opened Firefox but partial options still wrong

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I'm using selenium to control Firefox, and load my default profile successfully(I can change my search engine or add page to my bookmark manually, then close it, and I can see the change in my program's opening Firefox) So I think my loading profile is all right.

But what I want to do is to make 'open new link in new tab instead of new window' true in Firefox's options. And it went wrong. I found that my Firefox opened manually was different from my program's opening Firefox on tab options page. Look at the tabs, they have different options. And my setting on the first browser about tabs can't convert to the second one. How to fix it? Thanks for advance.

```
            self.window.driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=self.window.driverPath,firefox_profile=self.window.profile)
```

[image]

[image: s://i.stack.imgur.com/dob2Q.png]

Comment: `using selenium to control Firefox` and `add page to my bookmark manually` both? What is your exact _usecase_?

Comment: I mean, I operate in Firefox like normal users, and close it. And then import this configuration file to see if I load successfully.